# Can we send an email whenever the workflow met with an error?

Tags: designer-workflow

I am having a sharepoint 2013 resuable designer workflow. So far it is running fine. However I need to know immediately if it went into an error state.

Do we have an out of box configuration for it?

Answer (score 1):

where are you setting this workflow ..if it is a list set a view to the list with workflow status column values when not equal to completed. set alert on the view and you will be notified immediately whenever it fails.
workflow status column is nothing but you will have with your workflow name.so for example your workflow name is "Error Notification" in view you have to create a view named "Not Completed" 
There are different numerals used for the workflow states for each see below

In Progress = 2
Approved = 16
Error Occurred = 3
Not Started = 0

So in your case create a view with name "Not Completed" and in the filter show items only when "your workflow name" is equal to 3. Once you set up the view set an alert on the view.

Or else go to designer and click on allfiles you can find workflow history list right click on the list and set an list workflow to send an email when it fails [image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried both the options. 
1. The workflow column is not available for filtering while creating the view.
2. I have few workflow errored items in the list however in 'Workflow History' list there are no items with description failed.

Comment: hi I have updated the my solution try it and let me know.

Comment: Thanks again. I am not able see my workflow column 'Error Notification' (I looked for my workflow name only).